# Changes around type inference check in Java 9

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, java-9

Code (Shortened the actual code to explain thew question).

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TypeReferenceTest {

    public static  class Model {
        public void setAbc(Abc<String> abc) { }
    }

    public static class Abc<T> {
        public Abc(T val) { }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> attrMap = new HashMap<>();
        attrMap.put("key", 0);
        Model m = new Model ();
        m.setAbc(new Abc<>(getAttrOrDefault(attrMap, "key", "Default")));
        System.out.println("Test completed.....");
    }

    public static <T extends Object> T getAttrOrDefault(Map<String, Object> attrMap, String attrName, T defaultValue) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T attrValue = (T)attrMap.get(attrName);
        return (attrValue == null) ? defaultValue : attrValue;
    }
}
```

Test

```
host:~/temp/test> /usr/local/java/jdk1.8/bin/javac TypeReferenceTest.java 
host:~/temp/test> file TypeReferenceTest.class 
TypeReferenceTest.class: compiled Java class data, version 52.0 (Java 1.8)
host:~/temp/test> /usr/local/java/jdk9/bin/java TypeReferenceTest
Test completed.....
host:~/temp/test> /usr/local/java/jdk9/bin/javac TypeReferenceTest.java 
host:~/temp/test> file TypeReferenceTest.class 
TypeReferenceTest.class: compiled Java class data, version 53.0
host:~/temp/test> /usr/local/java/jdk9/bin/java TypeReferenceTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String
    at TypeReferenceTest.main(TypeReferenceTest.java:18)
host:~/temp/test>
```

Please note the exception when the same code was run on Java  9 compiled code. I understand the the reason why code caused ClassCastException, but it is OK if code is compiled with Java 8 (runtime being Java 9 in both the cases). To see the difference, I used javap and disassembled the code to see the diff.

Java 8 compiled disassembled code (only section of interest here)

```
  39: invokestatic  #11                 // Method getAttrOrDefault:(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

  42: invokespecial
```

Java 9 compiled disassembled code (only section of interest here)

```
  39: invokestatic  #11                 // Method getAttrOrDefault:(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  42: checkcast     #12                 // class java/lang/String
  45: invokespecial
```

Noting the difference in Java 9 compiled disassembled code, it is explicitly checking the type in relevant instruction. Of course, that should have been easily inferred from the code that return type should be string but there was no explicit check earlier.

Questions: Has there been some change around type inference in Java 9 and adding explicit check? If yes, where can I find the details (could not find in changelog)? Is it some compilation default option that has been changed in Java 9 that is adding this explicit type check in java 9?

Thanks,
Mozaffar

Comment: Sounds like you want to disable to type check. Why? What problem do you have with the code actually enforcing the static type of your code? Write valid code, then you won't have a problem.

Comment: @Andreas  _Sounds like you want to disable to type check. Why?_ - I don't want to, it is a good check, but one piece of code suddenly started resulting exception. My question is where can I find the changelog in Java 9 related to this change and possibly info about more such changes.

Comment: You should rather search your codebase for suspicious `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` occurrences, rather than searching the changelogs for things whose impact is really hard to predict (without looking at the particular source code, which brings you back to the preferred solution). The method can be simplified to `return attrMap.getOrDefault(attrName, defaultValue);` by the way.

Comment: @Holger Existing old code can be changed and improved but I believe simply changing that method to `return attrMap.getOrDefault(attrName, defaultValue);` will change the existing behavior here.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this was a bug in java-8, most probably [this one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058199). And it got fixed in java-9. The `checkcast` must be there to begin with since you only take `Abc<String>` as input, in my opinion.